# Spring Hibernate SessionUtils connection.close

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Question regarding following code

```
SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(getSessionFactory()).getConnection()
```

Does connection checked out from above line of code required to be closed upon method finished work?

Comment: what does getDataSource does? please post the code of the SessionFactoryUtils class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer depends on how you're using it. The intent is that this can be called multiple times within a transaction, and if you're using it this way then you definitely would not want to close it.